# Ionic 3 app cannot build due to package

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, sass, ngx-bootstrap

I have an Ionic app and am trying to use [NGX-Bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap) with it, but my app cannot build due to the way the package is organized.

> sass: node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.scss, line:
>   1
>               It's not clear which file to import for '@import "utils/scss/variables"'. Candidates:
>               utils/scss/variables.scss utils/scss/variables.css Please delete or rename all but one of these files.
>
> ```
>    L1:  @import './utils/scss/variables';
>    L2:  @import './utils/scss/mixins';
> ```

[This issue](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/2641) mentions the problem, but claims it should be fixed in the next version.  I am running v 2.0.2 (latest) and the error still remains.

This is my setup:

```
Ionic Framework: 3.9.2
Ionic App Scripts: 3.1.2
Angular Core: ^4.4.3
Angular Compiler CLI: 4.4.3
Node: 9.1.0
OS Platform: macOS High Sierra
Navigator Platform: MacIntel
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
```

And I'm running typescript v 2.3.4.

Any assistance would be great.

Comment: I have the same issue; Can you tell me how you resolved it please ?

Comment: Sadly I had to remove the package.  Haven't heard anything since

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jeremy. I removed the package too.